# HTML Form posting correct values in Database except for TinyINT

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, post

I'm kinda new to php and I'm having a bit of a struggle getting the values from an HTML form into my Database. The column I'm having a problem with is a TINYINT. In my understanding this can have 2 values, 1 or 0 but I'm not getting this result in my database. The rest of the form seems to work accordingly. Here is an example of my code and logic;

The HTML form looks like this:

```
    <form action="" method="post" id="createBoard" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="boardTitle">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="boardTitle" id="boardTitle">

        <label for="privateSwitch">Private?</label>
        <input id="privateSwitch" name="status" type="checkbox" checked>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

The PHP logic before the html is:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    try {
        // create prepared statement
        $newBoard = new Board();
        $newBoard->setBoardName($_POST["boardTitle"]);
        if (empty($_POST['status'])){
            $privateSwitch = 0;
        } else {
            $privateSwitch = 1;
        }
        $newBoard->setPrivateSwitch($privateSwitch);
        if ($newBoard->create()){
            $feedback = "Board saved";
            header("Location: user_uploads.php?success=true");
        }

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

And the class included looks as following:

Setter & Getter:

```
public function setPrivateSwitch($privateSwitch)
{
  $this->privateSwitch = $privateSwitch;
}

public function getPrivateSwitch()
{
    return $this->privateSwitch;
}
```

The fuction for creating a "board":

```
public function create()
{
    $conn = Db::getInstance();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO board (boardTitle, userID, private) VALUES (:boardTitle, :userID, :private)");
    $stmt->bindValue(":boardTitle", $this->boardTitle);
    $stmt->bindValue(":userID", $_SESSION["id"]);
    $stmt->bindValue(":private", $this->private);
    return $stmt->execute();
}
```

The Board is being created in the database but the private row is still getting NULL values. It looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of the Database Table board]

[image: Structure of the Database]

What am I missing here?
Thanks for your time and feedback!

Comment: A TINYINT value can be more than 0 or 1. The max range is 0-255. You may be thinking of BYTE.

Comment: *"TINYINT. In my understanding this can have 2 values, 1 or 0"* ... `TINYINT`, by default, is actually `INT(3)` with a possible range of -128 > +127 or 0 - 255 depending on whether it's signed or not.

Comment: Show the rest of the class. In the table it's "private", but the part of the class you included in your question doesn't show you setting that column name

Comment: Thanks guys for this information, @Sloan Thrasher as you said I was thinking of a BYTE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setter function seems to be the issue. Try changing setter function to:

```
public function setPrivateSwitch($privateSwitch)
{
  $this->private = $privateSwitch;
}
```

and getter to:

```
public function getPrivateSwitch()
{
  return $this->private;
}
```

Comment: ... or to ensure it can only be 0|1 you could do `$this->private = $privateSwitch ? 1 : 0;`